# Реализация пост запроса в visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Реализацию взял из примера но все равно ошибки, возможно, потому что пример не для UWP помогите чайнику... Если я удалю request.ContentLength и закрывания потоков. Что то озменится в UWP? Просто я решил, что в UWP все потоки сами прекращаются.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код из немного другого примера, но суть таже. Студия как и в тот раз ругается на .Close() и ContentLength

```
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://www.contoso.com/PostAccepter.aspx ");
        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST";
        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
        string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close ();
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
        // Display the content.
        Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close ();
        dataStream.Close ();
        response.Close ();
```

Далее я некоторые удалил а некоторые чуть изменил, ошибок теперь нет и даже работает(прошу проверить нынешний код на провильность)

```
// Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("Какой-нибудь мой сервак");
        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST";
        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
        string postData = "action=101&login=" + Login.Text + "&pass=" + Pass.Text;
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        // Display the status.
        Resp.Text = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription;
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the content.
        JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(responseFromServer);
        JToken jsonArray_Item = jsonArray.First;
      string  Answer = jsonArray_Item.Value<string>("answer");
        Resp.Text += Answer;
        if (Answer == "ok")
        {
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        }
```

Comment: Отформатируйте сообщение: нехорошо вставлять код картинкой.

Comment: Удалять request.ContentLenght нельзя, закрытие потоков тоже сделано правильно. Не знаю, откуда вы копировали пример - но код у вас правильный, как в MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.contentlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35619622/webrequest-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-getresponse-for-windows-10-univer/35621057

Там по ссылкам находится и другой ответ - прямо про ContentLength, почитайте, очень полезная информация в обоих постах и ссылках на MSDN.

Суть в двух словах: класс WebRequest сделан в UWP иначе, поэтому нельзя один-в-один копировать примеры из "класического" .Net.

Comment: @Denisok приведите код примера текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: @PashaPash картинку я приложил чтобы было видна ошибка, но как просили добавил сам код

Answer (score 1):

А зачем эта возня с WebRequest? Вот рабочий пример. Обернуть в using и try-catch и можно юзать.

```
public async Task<string> SendPostRequest(string url, string body)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return content;
    }
```

Comment: А зачем тогда вообще нужен WebRequest? И  что означает  - Task<string> ?)

Comment: И что значит эта строка `httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");`

Comment: Task<string> означает что создается асинхронная задача, которая вернет строку. На первую часть вопрсоа про WebRequest ничего внятного ответить не могу)

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json"); добавляет заголовки, сообщает серверу, что в ответ ждет данные в формате json, можно удалить, если не требуется конкретно их указывать.

Comment: Спасибо) Помогли)

Comment: А нет, еще вопрос, как обратится к этой функции `string Answer = SendPostRequest("Моя сервак", "Строка которую передаю");` - так? @Make Makeluv

Comment: Вот так: string Answer = await SendPostRequest("Моя сервак", "Строка которую передаю");
Перед методом где это будет вызываться надо будет поставить ключевое слово async.